# PhpMyAdmin navigation tree doesn't expand

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've put PhpMyAdmin v 4.7.7 on a Debian 9 server with PHP 7.0. Most of it works, but a number of features don't. One of them is the navigation tree in the left panel: it simply doesn't expand (clicking a server name should list table names). The Ajax response from navigation.php is `{"reload_flag":"1","success":false,"error":""}`. Success obviously should be true, and the response should contain the HTML with the table list.

I don't see any JS errors in the browser console. There also are no errors in the server's PHP error log.

The same setup (literally the same PhpMyAdmin files) runs fine on my Windows 10 laptop.

As I've recently upgraded to PHP 7 on the server, maybe I've overlooked a required PHP extension? curl, mbstring, mysqli are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Clearing cookies solved it. Left by a previous version.